# get_headers only returns 200 when a string literal is used in the URL

Tags: php, php-curl

In my script I'm reaching out to an API to get a task ID that should be used to download one or more files. The connection to the APIs is working as expected and after some processing I'm able to get the ID I need from the appropriate endpoint.

In order to proceed to downloading the file(s), I need the file name that is returned by the `Content-Disposition` header, so I used `get_headers()` as follows to get the headers:

```
    function downloadFiles() {
    
      $taskID = getTaskID();

      // Call with variable won't work
      $url = "https://example.com/api/v1/document/export/$taskID";

      $opts = [
          'http' => [
              'header' => [
                  "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode('myapikey'),
                  'Accept: */*'
              ]
          ]
      ];
      $context = stream_context_create($opts);
      $headers = get_headers($url, true, $context);

     return $headers;
   }

#########################################################

    function downloadFiles() {
    
      $taskID = getTaskID();

      // Call with literal string works
      $url = "https://example.com/api/v1/document/export/xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";

      $opts = [
          'http' => [
              'header' => [
                  "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode('myapikey'),
                  'Accept: */*'
              ]
          ]
      ];
      $context = stream_context_create($opts);
      $headers = get_headers($url, true, $context);

     return $headers;
   }
```

If I use the code above with `$taskID` as a variable I get back a `HTTP/1.1 204 No Content` without the `Content-Disposition`, however, if I hardcode the task ID string that I get back from my `getTaskID()` function (correctly fetching the string id), it works with a 200 and the needed header.

Is there any caching going on here? Is just not possible to use a static value here as the ID changes after each call to the download endpoint.

Comment: `var_dump($taskID);` and tell us what you get

Comment: Had done it. I get an expected string(36).

Comment: Does it require 36, or 35 (xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx is 35)?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really count my "x" in the example. But the format is correct as it should.